# Matching 2 keywords list using NLP

Tags: classification, nlp, text

I have two lists and I want to identify which elements are common (same or similar in meaning or context) in the list. Which NLP algorithm we should use.

```
list-1= [US, Apple, Trump, Biden, Mango, French, German]

list-2= [State, iphone, ipad, ipod, president, person, Fruit, Language, Country]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest implementation would be using following steps :

```
Step 1 : Iterate through both the list 
Step 2 : Calculate the Cossine Similarity between each word in list1 with list2
Step 3 : Decide the threshold on cossine similarity. Higher means stricter
```

Code would be as follows:

```
list_1 = [ US, Apple, Trump, Biden, Mango, French, German]
list_2 = [State, iphone, ipad, ipod, president, person, Fruit, Language, Country]


# Download the package and model : 
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

similarity_dict = {}
for word_list1 in list_1:
    for word_list2 in list_2:
         model = Word2Vec.load(path/to/your/model)
         cosine_similarity = model.wv.similarity(word_list1, word_list2)
```

Pros :

1. Easy to implement
2. Uses Word2vec aso very reliable as word2vec ensure context
3. Easy to undertsand

Cons :

1. The code has complexity of O(n*n)
2. It will not work with Words which are out of vocabulary in word2vec

Comment: I have already tried cosine similarity. Its not effective, please suggest some other algorithm.

Comment: Cosine similarity is just a method to calculate distance.. When you used cosine similarity how did you get vector to compare is what makes all the difference?